# Javascript (react native): how to avoid that = this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'd like to **avoid** `let that = this;` because it seems to be a dirty solution. Is it e.g. possible to use `.bind(this)` anyhow?

My **current code**:

```
// ... 
componentDidMount() {
    let that = this; // <- how to avoid this line?
    this.props.myService.listensTo('action', (data) => {
        that.handleData(data); 
    });
}

handleData(data) {
    // handle data
}
// ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `this.props.myService.listensTo('action', this.handleData.bind(this));`?

Comment: You don't need the `that` trick with Javascript arrow functions.

Comment: React already binds this when you use arrow functions.

Comment: @Jecoms - It has nothing to do with React. It's a standard feature of ES6. See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for details on how arrow functions deal with `this`.

Comment: Indeed, just poor wording.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically arrow functions will help with this and since React-Native doesnt have to deal with browser compatibility you can define you're functions like this:

```
handleData = (data) => {
  this.setState({ data });
}
```

You won't ever have to .bind or that=this if you use this.

Comment: Also, for the componentDidMount, you didn't even need to do that=this, because you used arrow functions.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is already bound because of the arrow function you've used.

```
// ... 
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.myService.listensTo(
        'action', 
        (data) => this.handleData(data)
    );
}

handleData(data) {
    // handle data
}
// ...
```